# How do I query all SSAS database connections?

Tags: ssas

I would like to know for example how many databases in my SSAS has sql connections.
Is there a way to query all of them together?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you looked at the SSAS DMVs?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh230820.aspx

Just run them in a normal MDX query pane

```
Select * from $System.discover_sessions
```